# C# asp.net 4 trying to check if session is empty, and getting error

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, session

I am trying to check if my `Session["User"]` is empty by using the next code and next redirect to my login screen, but no matter what I'm trying I am getting [CS1061](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs1061) error:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["User"] == null)
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/?i=login");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where do you get this error? On the login page?

Comment: When i'm trying to browse, on the page, runtime, not compilation

Comment: In which line the error occurred? Is that `Session["User"]` check getting the exception?

Comment: The problem is precisely what the exception is telling you. That you are calling a class or an object that does not exist in your current context. Since you have not posted your code, its difficult to tell but my guess is either your session or response.redirect is not referenced properly. The best thing to do in this situation is to see where the error is coming from is it session variable or the response.redirect, after identifying which you can add the reference by adding this line "using reference_name" on top of your code

Comment: Thanks, I checked my self over again and I just rewrote my code and it worked.